# What does a dot after an integer mean in python?

Tags: python

I am looking at this line of python code (which seems to run properly):

```
import numpy as np
yl = 300 + 63*np.exp(-x/35.)
```

What is the dot doing after the 35? what does it do? Is it a signal to python that 35 is a float and not an integer? I have not seen this before. Thanks!

Comment: It's the same as `35.0`, a `float`. Similarly you can use `.5` for `0.5`, but you can't use `.` for `0.0`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is easy to test, and you're right. The dot signals a float.

```
$ python
>>> 1.
1.0
>>> type(1.)
<type 'float'>
```

Answer (score 8):

Float

Next time, try to explore this using Python

```
r= 34.

print type(r)
```

Output: `<type 'float'>`

Answer (score 0):

It tells python to treat `3` as a `float()`. Its just a convenient way to make a number a float for division purposes then having to explicitly call `float()` on it.

For example:

```
my_float = 3.

typed_float = float(3)

my_float == typed_float
#=> True

type(my_float)
#=> <type 'float'>
```

In this case you need to typecast to a float to avoid the pitfalls of integer division.

Comment: Note that as of Python 3, this is no longer necessary. Saying `1/3` works the way you would actually expect it to, giving 0.333... as result, rather than zero.

Comment: And use `//` for integer division (going off on a tangent).